# Disabled cell's button click event fire

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which there is a button in one cell. Now when I am disabling that cell, the cell gets disabled but on clicking upon that cell, button click event is happening. So instead of disabling the cell, I disabled the button. Now everything working fine, but I wanted to know that why on disabling the cell, button click event was getting fired?
my code snippet is like below:

To disable cell-(previous approach) ---

```
grid.rows[i].cells[1].disabled=true;
```

To disable button:(new approach)--

```
grid.rows[i].cells[1].firstChild.disabled=true;
```

Comment: I see nothing that disabled is valid in a cell in the [html spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6).

Comment: yes it is valid . you can test it by simply making a table having one button in one cell. try both approach mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [html4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled):

> The following elements support the disabled attribute: BUTTON, INPUT, OPTGROUP, OPTION, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

Looking at the [html4 spec for td](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6), there is nothing saying disabled is valid.

So that means setting disabled on the table's cell does nothing. You need to set individually on the form elements inside of the cell.

What you are doing now is randomly setting some property on the cell that means nothing to it. It is the same thing as setting `grid.rows[i].cells[1].foobar=true;`. It means nothing, but the cell has it attached to it.

Comment: agree with your answer,but why then it is not throwing an error.

Comment: Why would it throw an error? There is nothing wrong setting it, it is valid, it just has no meaning to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe happening because when u disable the cell then the button element does not get disabled. It still remains enabled, unlike the cell.

Comment: no, the cell is getting disabled. but the button inside that will remain enable. but my question is since the cell is disabled , how the button click event is getting fired.